# Nested if statement in SQL stored procedure error. Expecting ), AND, or OR

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that will check if a datetime value in a column in a table (it will have only one value in the column). If it exists, I want to see if the datetime value is withing +-5 minutes of current time. If it is then I will execute another stored procedure and then update that datetime.

If the value didn't exist at all then I insert current date to the column.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Procedural code like stored procedures is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You should eliminate the top 1 in your exists. It is not needed. Also when you set your variable you have top 1 but no order by so you don't know which row you will get. Last but not least....look at the AND predicate in your nested IF. You are comparing your variable to a calculated value of the same variable. You have some sort of logic issue here but not quite sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange there's only 1 row in this table. one row and one column, just to keep track of date. I am updating that variable by adding 24 hours to it.

Comment: If there is only 1 then why bother typing top 1? :) The real issue though is your where predicates have serious logical problems. You are comparing the same value to itself. You set your variable and then check to see if its value is < > to a date added to the same value. No matter what date you find it will always evaluate your inner IF to true. You need to be comparing your variable to getdate()

Comment: @SeanLange wow...I'm an idiot. It's suppose to check if it's +- 5 minutes from current date. Doh! I edited my code above

Comment: Pretty sure that was the only real issue you had going on there. Glad I was able to get you to see it. I tried a couple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    IF ( @DateToKeepForTrim >=  dateadd(MINUTE,-5,(SELECT top 1 TrimCheck.TrimCheckDate FROM TrimCheck)) AND @DateToKeepForTrim <= dateadd(MINUTE,5, @DateToKeepForTrim)
```

Should read:

```
    IF ( @DateToKeepForTrim >=  dateadd(MINUTE,-5,(SELECT top 1 TrimCheck.TrimCheckDate FROM TrimCheck)) AND @DateToKeepForTrim <= dateadd(MINUTE,5, @DateToKeepForTrim) )
```